# Is there a native function that checks if a value is inside of an enum?

Tags: objective-c, enums

I'm trying to put `UILabel`s inside of an `NSDictionary`, I'm using tags as key, but the problem is, not all of the labels inside of the view is needed, the tags of the `UILabel`s that is needed is also inside of an enum.

So what I want to do is, check the tag if it exist inside of the enum then add it to dictionary with tag as key.

```
for (NSObject *obj in [self.formView subviews]) {

    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)obj;

        // Here is where I want to add the check before I do this line
        labelDict[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",label.tag]] = label;
    }
}
```

**For Future Readers:**

If you are also iterating on an NSArray type of object like the code above, you should use the NSArray function `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` instead, **this is the answer**, doesn't it look more pretty:

```
[self.formView.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            UILabel *label = (UILabel *)obj;
            if ( label.tag >= TEXTFIELDTYPE_MIN_VAL && label.tag <= TEXTFIELDTYPE_MAX_VAL ) {
                labelDict[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",label.tag]] = label;
            }
        }
}];
```

Comment: That is not possible. What you can do at the very least is create create a for loop with the start number of the minimum of the tag's numbers then the end number of the max of the tag's numbers, from there add it to the dictionary

Comment: Is your enum sequential? If it is, you simply need to check if it's in that range.

Comment: Yes I made it that way from 100 - 121, because my current code relies on the for(int a=100; a<=121; a++) before adding it to the dictionary, I just want to know if there is a native function that can make it more efficient because calling the loop x times the number of subviews looks ugly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective-C enums are inherited from C enums and cannot be reflected at runtime. Without abusing debug symbols (which would be an overly complicated task for a slow and unreliable result), I believe that it would be impossible to come up with a function that would tell you if an arbitrary value is a member of an arbitrary enum.

One possible workaround would be to create a NSSet that contains all the enum values you have, and check if your label's tag exists within that set. Otherwise, if your enum is sequential, you can check that the tag is between your enum's minimum value and maximum value.

Comment: Yes my actual code is actually like what you say, it depends on the min and max of the enum values, I just wanted it to be more dynamic and efficient because the extra loop is ugly and inefficient. Thank you for the insight

Comment: Wait–extra loop? You don't need a loop to check if it's a member or not, you just need `tag >= myEnumMinimum && tag <= myEnumMaximum`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, instead of for loop of all subviews, run for loop of your enum values,
hopefully the enum values are in sequence then only this below code would work:

```
for(NSInteger tagVal = enum.firstEnum; tagVal <= enum.lastEnum; tagValue++) {
   NSObject *obj = [self.formView viewWithTag:tagVal];
   if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)obj;

        // Here is where I want to add the check before I do this line
        labelDict[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",label.tag]] = label;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what my actual code looks like, take my +1 :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ([[dict allKeys] containsObject:lbl]) {

    }
```